Until otherwise signposted, do Dutch highways default to a 130 km/h maximum speed even during daytime?
Dutch highways default to a 130 km/h speed limit (per article 21 of the Dutch Traffic Law). In the current situation, all Dutch highways have a reduced speed limit of 100 km/h between 6:00 and 19:00 hours. Source (in Dutch).
I spoke to a driving instructor who mentioned an examiner who argued that the reduced maximum speed is only in effect after it is signposted on the road. That mostly happens a little bit after the entrance ramp. As such, they reasoned that the on-ramp (unless a different speed limit is indicated) has a maximum speed of 130 km/h.
I'm wondering to what extent that reasoning holds water from a legal perspective. For example, is there jurisprudence on (alleged) speeding (100-130 km/h) on the on-ramp during the reduced speed limit time which was then contested in court?

I doubt there would be much police control on ramps (and consequently fewer jurisprudence). For accidents, the legal limit does not matter as much since you can be at fault if you drive over a reasonable speed that may be lower than the legal limit.

And is there a "highway starts" sign before you enter the ramp?

@xngtng yes ramps have a G01 sign indicating the road is a highway. It's a bit of theoretical question but the procedure of entering a highway is common enough that there should be an answer. I'm also happy to receive theoretical answers (based on reasoning around traffic law). The reason I think it's an interesting question is that it can sometimes be safer to drive faster so you can undertake slow traffic (legal because of road markings) but you wouldn't want to do so if it turns out to be illegal.
